# Applying lambda function to a pandas rolling window series

Tags: python, pandas, series, rolling-computation

I have a function which takes an array and a value, and returns a value. I would like to apply it to my Series `s` on a rolling basis, so the array is always the rolling window. Here's a minimal example of what I've tried (unsuccessfully), using `np.random.choice` in place of my real function. I find lots of examples for finding rolling means and other built-in functions, but can't get it to work for my arbitrary lambda function.

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
rolling_window = s.rolling(3)
```

First attempt:

```
new_values = s.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(rolling_window, size=1))
```

> ValueError: a [a is the first positional param of choice(), so refers to 'rolling_window'] must be 1-dimensional or an integer

Another attempt:

```
new_values = rolling_window.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(size=1))
```

> TypeError: choice() takes at least 1 positional argument (0 given)

...How do I apply an arbitrary lambda function (taking an array and a value) on each value in my Series, on each rolling-array window in my Series?

Comment: `rolling_window.apply(lambda x: ....)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, if all you want to do is apply a function on the window, your second attempt comes close:

```
rolling_window.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x, size=1))
```

---

However, you can circumvent the use of the `lambda` like this:

```
rolling_window.apply(np.random.choice, kwargs={'size' : 1})

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    4.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    7.0
7    7.0
8    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Additional arguments to the function you pass go in `args` and `kwargs`.

Comment: How to access individual elements inside the window in the function applied? I tried `x[1]` or something like that without success.